# Missing the linking contacts feature in Contacts on Mac

Tags: macos, contacts, contacts.app

I've noticed that the linking contacts feature doesn't seem to be available on my Mac, even though it's mentioned in the [Contacts user guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/contacts/link-contacts-from-different-accounts-adrb33f38d93/mac#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Contacts%20app%20on,Merge%20and%20Link%20Selected%20Cards.) for macOS Ventura 13. I've tried linking my contacts on my iPhone, and it works fine, but the linking won't sync to my Mac.

Contacts user guide says:

> In the list of contacts, select the cards you want to link, then
> choose Card > Link Selected Cards.

However, the option is simply not present in the Contacts application menu on my Mac:
[image: Screenshot from Contacts with a missing linking option]

Thus, I want to be able to link contacts on my Mac, or at least have the linking sync up from my iPhone onto my Mac.

What I have tried to (to no avail):

- Link other cards (it's obviously not the case, given that there is no problem using iPhone)
- Restart Contacts
- Turn off/on the computer
- Try with a different Apple ID under a different Mac user
- Resync Contacts with iCloud on both devices

Any feedback from other Mac users, especially any possible solutions to this issue, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details and information to highlight exactly what you need. Also, what have you done and how didn't it work? Please also provide a screenshot, it would help.

Comment: @Thinkr I've updated the post.

Comment: The guide states "if you have multiple cards for one contact, you can link them" Your example shows two distinct contacts.

Comment: The guide also states: "If you use several accounts in Contacts".  What's the second account?

Comment: "Merge" (as per your screenshot) usually appears instead of "link", if the cards are from the same account (e.g. iCloud), while "link" replaces it, when the cards selected are from two different accounts (e.g. iCloud and Google).

Comment: @Tetsujin, As I wrote above, I tried this with contacts, some of which were nearly identical and some of which were vastly different. Also, the Contacts app for iPhone has an equivalent feature, and card info has no effect on their linking there. In fact, you can even link completely blank contacts.

Comment: @Redarm, the full phrase is "If you use several accounts in Contacts, you may have multiple cards for a contact...". While the article cites different accounts as an example, it does not say that the cards must necessarily be from different accounts. Instead, the focus is on the mere existence of multiple entries for a contact. Moreover, if this feature were not available individually for cards from the same account, the option would be present in the menu grayed out. But it is not. Also, why does the same feature work seamlessly with any card on iPhone, no matter from what account, then?

Comment: @Redarm, You are right. Indeed, the contact linking feature works differently on Mac. I added a Google account to Contacts and tried linking cards, one from Google and one from iCloud. It worked. However, this just means that the feature needs to be improved if developers put a priority on a consistent user experience across the Apple ecosystem. Well, now I don't even really sure whether to delete or update the post.

Comment: @TimofeySuyargulov Patience; they are working on it (turning macOS into iOS).  I'm just miffed that it's not the other way round.  If you want to speed it up, leave feedback.